# Перевести дату аналогично GetSysTime в C++ на PHP или JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, c++

К примеру дата — `2012-12-18 20:44:20`
Если написать в С++ `GetSysTime().Get();` то выходит число `63523082653`
Как получить такое же число в *PHP* или *JS*?

Comment: А что это за функция такая GetSysTime()?

Comment: GetSysTime() функция перевода даты в вид 2012-12-18 20:44:20 из цифр в примере. а потом пишет в таблицу с помощью GetSysTime().Get(); из описания фреймворка Ultimate++ удалось найти только, что Get() преобразует дату в целое, без каких либо подробностей

Comment: А какая у вас ОС и какой компилятор? Как-то я не могу найти документации на GetSysTime(), что меня несколько удивляет...

Comment: К сожалению код не мой, я веб программист) и мне нужно распознать их код) Так что боюсь что знаю не больше вашего, но мне подсказали что типа как Unix time  Но с 1900 года а не с 1970

Comment: а можете подробней объяснить проблему? зачем Вам в php или javascript коде (я так понимаю в сайте?) числовое значение даты/времени которое Вы потом не сможете стандартными средствами языка обработать(форматированый вывод, сравнение и т д)?

Comment: тогда может так? 70 лет = 2,208,988,800 секунд. Тогда время будет time() + 2208988800 . Но так тоже не получаються цифры рядом с 63523082653

Comment: Да, интересный вопрос зачем такое хитрое время где-то на сайте :-)

Comment: @totorro это могут быть не секунды, а 100нс интервалы, например...

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов та да. Самое интересное что у них же на сайте в документации я не нашел описания этой функции http://www.ultimatepp.org/src$Core$DateTime$en-us.html Хотя в примерах кода она встречается

Comment: @totorro да они же просто лапочки тогда!

Comment: 63523082653 19.12.3982 22:44:13 вот гляди) снизу комментатор оставил цифры) почти та же дата но перебор на 1984 года, 1 день и 2 часа..)

Comment: Пришел к выводу что их формат просто добавляет ко времени unix 62293449593 секунд, все проще чем казалось) спасибо за помощь

Comment: @zoinx2012 А вы разные даты пробовали и везде одинаковое смещение? Разные года (разницу в 5-ть лет)?

Answer (score 1):

На php можно через strtotime либо через класс `DateTime`. Через strtotime:

```
echo strtotime('2012-07-25 14:35:08');
```

На выходе получим:

```
1343219708
```

через класс `DateTime`: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.gettimestamp.php

На js:

```
var timestamp = new Date("2012-07-25 14:35:08");
var timestamp = timestamp.getTime();
```

**Update**

Только заметил, по формату не подходит, так что мой ответ не верный. Проще использовать UNIX формат в C++: `GetUtcTime` вместо `GetSysTime`

Answer (score 0):

Затянул ваш вопрос, добрый человек нашел исходники метода [GetSysTime().Get()](https://github.com/ultimatepp/mirror/blob/master/uppsrc/Core/TimeDate.cpp#L493).

Аналог на php примерно выглядит вот так:

```
function IsLeapYear($year){
    return (int)(($year % 4 == 0 && $year % 100 != 0) || $year % 400 == 0);
}

function DateGet($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second){
    $s_month_off = [
       0,  31,  59,  90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334
    ]; 
    $y400 = ($year / 400 ) - 2;
    $ym = $year - $y400 * 400;
    return $y400 * (400 * 365 + 100 - 3) +
            $ym * 365 + $s_month_off[$month - 1] + ($day - 1) +
           ($ym - 1) / 4 - ($ym - 1) / 100 + ($ym - 1) / 400 + 1 +
           ((int)($month > 2) * IsLeapYear($ym));
}

function GetStrangeTime($date){
    list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = array_values(date_parse($date));
    return DateGet($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) * 24*3600 + ($hour*3600) + ($minute*60) + $second;
}

echo GetStrangeTime("2012-12-18 20:44:20");
```

На javascript примерно:

```
function IsLeapYear($year){
    return (($year % 4 == 0 && $year % 100 != 0) || $year % 400 == 0);
}

function DateGet($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second){
    var $s_month_off = [
       0,  31,  59,  90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334
    ]; 
    var $y400 = ($year / 400 ) - 2;
    var $ym = $year - $y400 * 400;
    return $y400 * (400 * 365 + 100 - 3) +
            $ym * 365 + $s_month_off[$month - 1] + ($day - 1) +
           ($ym - 1) / 4 - ($ym - 1) / 100 + ($ym - 1) / 400 + 1 +
           (($month > 2) * IsLeapYear($ym));
}

function GetStrangeTime($date){
    var $year = $date.getFullYear();
    var $month = $date.getMonth()+1;
    var $day = $date.getDate();
    var $hour = $date.getHours();
    var $minute = $date.getMinutes();
    var $second = $date.getSeconds();
    console.log($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second);
    return Math.round(DateGet($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) * 24*3600 + ($hour*3600) + ($minute*60) + $second);
}

console.log(GetStrangeTime(new Date("2012-12-18 20:44:20")));
```

Все результаты выходят на 16 часов больше чем в приведенном примере, найти причину не удалось, если кто то сможет объяснить такое поведение будет замечательно. Можно заметить что нет никакой манипуляции с датой, как в случаи с `strtotime` и аналогами работы с Unix временем, там считается только разница между 1970 годом и вашей датой (стандарт и пример реализации расчета можно найти [здесь](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15)).